# Progress bar on data binding in vb6 application

Tags: data-binding, datagrid, vb6, grid

Can I use progress bar during grid binding with ADODC control in vb 6 application.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but there is no progress to show on it.  It is a one-step operation really.